# SecItemAdd creating two identities

Tags: iphone, certificate, identity, keychain

I'm developing an application for IPhone that needs a certificate to call some services, so I'm adding a certificate to my keychain doing this:

```
 SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certificadoData);
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
 [dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)(cert) forKey:(__bridge id<NSCopying>)(kSecValueRef)];
 OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);
```

When I list all the kSecClassIdentity before this code, the result is none and, after this code, the return are two identities and one certificate. 
When I tried to use the identities, one is working correctly but the other don't. Why the SecItemAdd is creating two kSecClassIdentity for one kSecClassCertificate? And how I can identify the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve this issue and from my reaserch the issue is that one of the identities contains private key and the other one contains public key.

So when you're trying to retrieve the identity you have to add

```
value: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate / kSecAttrKeyClassPublic
key: kSecAttrKeyClass
```

to the dictionary used as filter in `SecItemCopyMatching` e.g.:

```
NSMutableDictionary *filterDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity, kSecClass,
                                             kSecMatchLimitAll,              kSecMatchLimit,
                                             kCFBooleanTrue,                 kSecReturnRef,
                                             kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,        kSecAttrKeyClass,
                                             nil];
```

Comment: This must be a Keychain bug, since it makes no sense to have multiple Identities per cert, nor to have an Identity that isn't associated with the private key. Have you filed a bug report with Apple?