# iOS useCredential: forAuthenticationChallenge is not using given credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, client-certificates

I have the somewhat unusual use case and apple's useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge can't cope (or maybe it's me?).

The issue is, that I am making two consecutive connections (the second is called after the first one has been completed) each with different credentials (different client certificate):

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

URLs of requests are:

```
https://my.url.com/ws/service1
https://my.url.com/ws/service2
```

Then I implement the delegate's method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] != 0) {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }

    NSURLCredential *newCredential = nil;
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [challenge protectionSpace];

    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {
        if (isFirstRequest) {
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials1 forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials2 forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
}
```

Credentials are created from identity (persistence flag has no effect whatsoever):

```
NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identityRef
                                                         certificates:certificates
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
```

I'm sure that both credentials are valid and that they should be working. But only the first call is successful. After that when the second request is made, `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` method is called and the correct `useCredential:forAuthenticationChallange` is called but it does not change the credentials and the first ones are used anyway!

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender/useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:) of - useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:

```
Attempt to use a given credential for a given authentication challenge. (required)

This method has no effect if it is called with an authentication challenge that has already been handled.
```

Is there a way to check if the challenge has already been handled or to reset the challenge so that the system does not use any cached credentials?

I already tried to erase cached credentials but the code below (from SO) always returned zero credentials:

```
- (void)eraseCredentials {
    NSString *urlString = @"my.url.com";
    NSURLCredentialStorage *credentialsStorage = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
    NSDictionary *allCredentials = [credentialsStorage allCredentials];

    if ([allCredentials count] > 0)
    {
        for (NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace in allCredentials)
        {
            if ([[protectionSpace host] isEqualToString:urlString])
            {
                NSDictionary *credentials = [credentialsStorage credentialsForProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
                for (NSString *credentialKey in credentials)
                {
                    [credentialsStorage removeCredential:[credentials objectForKey:credentialKey] forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** What I already tried is to add the . or # after the URL as mentioned in [TLS Session Cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html) or here at StackOverflow but I don't think that's the issue here because my `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` is called correctly multiple times as expected...jest the given credentials doesn't work.

**Update:** the request itself is being built as follows:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[self resourceURLWithName:name]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Previously it was only:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[self resourceURLWithName:name]];
```

But there was no change in behaviour.

**Update 2:** In the end it wasn't issue with useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge: but it was an issue with identities. The one I used seemed to be ok but it wasn't. See my answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713368/secitemadd-creating-two-identities/30263488#30263488)

Answer (score 0):

Implement below delegate method

```
- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: I already used this piece of code but in the end it was not even necessary... the problem was elsewhere, I will update my question